# How to display mysql_select result in servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I've tried a few things but i'm not able to get the output and its taking too much time just to show the output screen....
For ex: in my situation the output should consist of a table with its output which is generated according to my program but instead its taking too much time just to perform the operation and after that its just showing table headers....

I've googled this but i'm not able to find the appropriate idea about this...

Thanks a million for anyone who can help..

This is my Code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
ResultSet result;
String dat,d,s,i,r;
int numcols,index,ans = 0;
ResultSetMetaData resultMd;
String rs = null;
d= request.getParameter("name");
s= request.getParameter("gen");
i= request.getParameter("indi");
r= request.getParameter("rea");
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
if(d!=null && i==null && r==null)
    ans=1;
else if(d!=null && i==null && r!=null)
    ans=2;
else if(d!=null && i!=null && r!=null)
    ans=3;
else if(d==null && i!=null && r!=null)
    ans=4;
else if(d==null && i==null && r!=null)
    ans=5;
else if(d!=null && i!=null && r==null)
    ans=6;
else if(d==null && i!=null && r==null)
    ans=7;

switch(ans)
{
case 1:
    rs="SELECT d.gndr_cod,d.age,d.wt,d.reporter_country,dr.drug_name,i.indi_pt,o.outc_cod,r.pt from demo d,drug dr,indi i,outc o,reac r where dr.drug_name='"+d+"' and d.gndr_cod='"+s+"' limit 25";
    break;
case 2:
    rs="SELECT d.gndr_cod,d.age,d.wt,d.reporter_country,dr.drug_name,i.indi_pt,o.outc_cod,r.pt from demo d,drug dr,indi i,outc o,reac r where dr.drug_name='"+d+"' and r.pt='"+r+"' and d.gndr_cod='"+s+"' limit 25";
    break;
case 3:
    rs="SELECT d.gndr_cod,d.age,d.wt,d.reporter_country,dr.drug_name,i.indi_pt,o.outc_cod,r.pt from demo d,drug dr,indi i,outc o,reac r where dr.drug_name='"+d+"' and r.pt='"+r+"' and i.indi_pt='"+i+"' and d.gndr_cod='"+s+"' limit 25";
    break;
case 4:
    rs="SELECT d.gndr_cod,d.age,d.wt,d.reporter_country,dr.drug_name,i.indi_pt,o.outc_cod,r.pt from demo d,drug dr,indi i,outc o,reac r where r.pt='"+r+"' and i.indi_pt='"+i+"' and d.gndr_cod='"+s+"' limit 25";
    break;
case 5:
    rs="SELECT d.gndr_cod,d.age,d.wt,d.reporter_country,dr.drug_name,i.indi_pt,o.outc_cod,r.pt from demo d,drug dr,indi i,outc o,reac r where r.pt='"+r+"' and d.gndr_cod='"+s+"' limit 25";
    break;
case 6:
    rs="SELECT d.gndr_cod,d.age,d.wt,d.reporter_country,dr.drug_name,i.indi_pt,o.outc_cod,r.pt from demo d,drug dr,indi i,outc o,reac r where dr.drug_name='"+d+"' and i.indi_pt='"+i+"' and d.gndr_cod='"+s+"' limit 25";
    break;
case 7:
    rs="SELECT d.gndr_cod,d.age,d.wt,d.reporter_country,dr.drug_name,i.indi_pt,o.outc_cod,r.pt from demo d,drug dr,indi i,outc o,reac r where i.indi_pt='"+i+"' and d.gndr_cod='"+s+"' limit 25";
    break;
}
out.print("<html>");
out.print("<head><title>Results</title></head>");
out.print("<body>");
try
{
    result=mystmt.executeQuery(rs);
    resultMd=result.getMetaData();
    numcols=resultMd.getColumnCount();
    out.print("<table border='1' width='100%'>");
    out.print("<tr><th>Drug Name</th><th>Sex</th><th>Age</th><th>Weight</th><th>Country</th>");
    out.print("<th>Indication</th><th>Reaction</th><th>Outcome</th>");
    out.print("</tr>");
    while(result.next())
    {
        out.print("<tr>");
        for(index=0; index<=numcols;index++)
        {
            dat=result.getString(index);
            out.print("<td>" +dat+"</td>");
        }
        out.print("</tr>");
    }
    out.print("</table>");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
out.print("</body></html>");}
```

Comment: Check in a debugger  or print what `numcols` gets. Also check if you have any stack trace in your server log. And the `index` for `getString()` starts from 1, not from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all, test your queries and if there are any performance issue, try to solve it. There could be huge amount of data as well what can not handle the runtime. See some log for RuntimeExceptions or Errors.

If your SQL query runs fast and returns not much rows then please edit your question  and make it simpliest as you can. Thanks. ;)

EDIT:

Try not to concatenate SQL queries, use binding instead, because database can not use statistics if you execute a brand new query, and you may running into SQLInjection issues.

EDIT2:

Please close your resources in finally block, and increase your connection thread limit if you have. Try only one SQL, try to make it siple to find out the source of the problem.

Comment: i tested those queries in sql they are performing those in secs but here in servlet i'm waiting for around 30 mins now